# .htaccess simple redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect

```
https://example.com/webrtcchat/[anyString]/[AnySTring]
->
https://example.com/chat/[anyString]/586c4a7251c2a
```

ex:

```
https://example.com/chat/54554/77d4d7d7 ->
https://example.com/webrtcchat/54554/77d4d7d7
```

I tried that with no success:

> RewriteRule  ^chat(.*)$  webrtcchat$1 [R=301,L]

This rules gives me bad result (inserts some /var/www)

```
https://example.com/var/www/example.com/webrtcchat/
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `Rewrite` or `Redirect` ?

Comment: yes maybe I am wrong: it should redirect

Comment: test this : `RedirectMatch 301 /chat(.*) /webrtcchat/$1` may work.